# What is the etymology of Sicilian "vanedda"?

Tags: etymology, semantics

This question arises from my research on [Si maritau Rosa](https://scn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_maritau_Rosa), a Sicilian song, where I found what seems to be a clear diminutive of *vanedda*, that is *vanidduzza*. Nowhere do I find that word directly, so I have no better guess as to its meaning than assuming it is indeed a diminutive of *vanedda* and see what the latter means.

And here I find [terralab](http://www.terralab.it/sishilianu/Vocabolario.htm), which gives me "stradina [little road] = vaneddha" – `ddh` is the way that site denotes the retroflex `dd` that others (me included… well, I use `đđ` to be very precise) indicate with plain `dd` – and [salviamoilsiciliano](http://www.salviamoilsiciliano.com/termini.asp), which explains *vanedda* as "piccola strada di campagna, o in città, vicolo" (small country road, or, in a city, alleyway). So I come to interpret "apru / a porta a vanidduzza" (which is the part of the song using *vanidduzza*) as "I open / the door to the small road".

Then I find [Sicilian Wiktionary](https://scn.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_vanedda), which gives me *a vanedda* as "a fessura, socchiuso" (in a slit-like fashion, ajar) in Italian, "entrebâillé, entrouvert" (ajar, half-open) in French, and surprisingly "small street, alley" in English. This gives me a meaning of "slit", with which I interpret "apru / a porta a vanidduzza" as "I half-open the door", which interpretation I prefer, also because of another version of the song giving me "Tegnu la porta aperta / La mettu a padiduzza", which seems to mean "I keep the door open / I put it ajar".

So I wonder: does *vanedda* have both senses, i.e. mean both "small street" and "slit"? And what sense is used in the song?

I try to go back into the etymology to see how this word formed and maybe choose the option closest to the meaning of its ancestors. I find [this blog post](http://pietromaccallini.blogspot.it/2010/03/etimologia-di-finestra.html) which, while discussing the etymology of *finestra*, mentions *vanedda* as a possible cognate of *vano*, itself possibly related (at least semantically) to *fanu* in Etruscan, which the post says Pittau (never heard that name before…) gives as the ancestor of "finestra" (=window). So *vanedda* would have formed as a diminutive of *vano*, originally meaning *passage*, via addition of -edda, or -ella in Italian (cfr. *Grotta delle Vanelle*, which I gather is a cave on the Etna volcano in Sicily), so it would mean "small passage" and therefore allow both the above interpretations.

However, when I look *vanus* (Latin) up on the Wiktionary, besides not finding any such sense (nor do I find it on [this dictionary](https://www.dizionario-latino.com/)), I find etymological information linking *vanus* to [PIE h₁weh₂-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81weh%E2%82%82-), which means "empty", and does not seem to support that other meaning, and is consistent with the meaning of "vanus", "vain", "empty", "useless".

So where does this word come from? Is it possible that it does come from *vanum*, which had a semantic shift from "empty(ness)" to "passage", and then to "road" and "slit"? Or is this a bogus etymology? And in the latter case, where does *vanedda* stem from?

And what does the word mean? Does it have both the meanings suggested above, or only one, and if the latter, which? And if it has both, which one is used in the song?

**Edit**

«Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage», says the *on hold* banner on this question. So it appears that the last part of the question, about the meaning of *vanedda*, is off-topic.

However, I [have reason to believe](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/is-this-question-about-etymology-and-meaning-really-off-topic) that the etymology part of th question is not off-topic. Alongside the etymology question, the question "How did the meaning of this word evolve in the ages?" should be on-topic.

So let me drop the "current meaning" part, and sum the question up as:

> Where does the word "vanedda" come from? Is it possible, as suggested [here](http://pietromaccallini.blogspot.it/2010/03/etimologia-di-finestra.html), that it relates to *vano* with that word having had the meaning of *passage* long ago? In that case, would it be correct to say that "vanedda" is *vano* + *-edda*, a diminutive suffix, and hence that the meaning evolved from "small passage" into either "narrow road" or "slit"?

Comment: [Meta thread concerning this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/nomination-for-reopening-another-etymology-question-which-had-a-part-about-curr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Antonino Traina, *Nuovo vocabolario siciliano-italiano compilato da Antonino Traina* (1869):

> (A Napoli dicon vinella, quasi vena o venatura della città. A me pare che il nostro derivi meglio da vano; ma non sappiamo se il nostro sia nato dal Napolitano o viceversa).

Michele Pasqualino, in *Vocabolario Siciliano etimologico, Italiano e Latino* (1795) mentions a similar connection (Latin *venula*), and expresses doubt that it comes from *veniendo*.

Note the age of these sources. I've been unable to find more recent ones.